# SSIS - Records not being picked up

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working with an SSIS that I inherited. There's a Data Flow that finds all records with status 0, and inserts them into a seperate table. The data flow uses a static query to pick up the new records.
I'm running into an issue when my SSIS runs, it does not insert the record into the destination table. It does however pick up many other records in the origin table.
To make things weirder, if I run this process from a job, there are always a few records (always the same ones) that don't get picked up. However if I run the job manually, they do get picked up.
I've checked and none of the records that we're picking up have nulls in any of the candidate keys. The error handling isn't called, so there isn't an error that occurs. I can insert the records into the destination table so it isn't a PK issue.
From the looks of it, these records are not seen by SSIS run by a job, but are when I run it manually. Anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Is there config of some sort that is called when run from the job?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the Source task in the Data Flow is using a connection with an Expression. The value of the Expression change your source and it can be different when you run the Package in the debugging mode vs when the package is run in the job. You can configure the expression to use parameters that can be use by the job.

You can check easily if the Connection is using an Expression because it has a FX before the connection name as the following image.

[Connection DBSource in the Connection Managers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhN6O.png)

Comment: So, I've checked the expressions and we can see that it's pointing to the same DB. Moreover, we can see that 95% of the records are picked up and put into the destination table when running from a job. That last 5% requires me to send by running SSIS directly.

Comment: Did you check if the expression is using a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

So we finally found the solution to the issue by testing on prod (kids, don't try this at home). It looks like the solution is simply to delete the SSIS and reply it.
Had anyone else seen this issue where SSIS just runs funny and needs to be redeployed?

Comment: Based on your question and answer.... it could be anything, but most likely the version deployed did not match the version that you were running in Visual Studio

Comment: I did redeploy as a test and was still getting the error. The connection was an expression, but I could see the data that it changed do I know that it was pointing to the right place. And no config file was affecting the connection.